# Getting an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" when trying to automatically increment data

Tags: java

I'm having a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` error because `i` is equal to `0` and not automatically incrementing. How can I fix this code so it can work as expected?

I want it to automatically increment each line of data read in the file read with Arrays. No matter where I put the `i++;` I get this issue. If I use another variable: Same issue.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class IdolResults
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        //construct Scanner
        //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("eleVotes1.txt"));
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(new File("eleVotes2.txt"));

        String[][] array;
        int[][] array2;
        String[] nameArray;
        int[] voteArray;
        int i = 0;

        while (in.hasNextLine())
        {   
             String name = in.next();
             int vote = in.nextInt();

             System.out.println(name);
             System.out.println(vote);

             //stuffhere: print, save name and vote, etc..
             //create an array and save info there
             array = new String[i][];
             array2 = new int[i][];

             array[i][0] = name;
             array2[i][1] = vote;

             //individually store name and votes
             nameArray = new String[10];
             voteArray = new int[10];

             nameArray[i] = name;
             voteArray[i] = vote;
             i++;

        }
    }//end of main
}//end of class
```

I eventually want to manipulate this stored data so I can make this:
Output expected:

```
Results for 2099
Idol Name        Votes Received    % of Total Votes
__________________________________________________      
Clarkson            80,000            14.4%
Seacrest            100,000           18.0%
Dunkleman           75,000            13.5%
Cowell              110,000           19.7%
Abdul               125,000           22.4%
Jackson             67,000            12.0%

Total Votes         557,000

The winner is Abdul!
```

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` happens when the array is empty, not when `i` is not incrementing.

Comment: Did you delete the previous version of this question?

Comment: Yes because the 3 answers I got ended up being deleted as well 20 minutes in because the same error showed up even with their answers. Then it didn't get a new answer for a while...

Comment: Questions are deleted with an additional penalty. Deleted questions could ban your account, which means that you could not ask questions anymore from then onwards.

Answer (score 5):

here

```
array = new String[i][];
array2 = new int[i][];
```

you're only instantiating your outer array.  you have to instantiate the inner arrays too

so

```
array[i] = new string[j];
```

Comment: i'm having trouble understanding how that would make sense if I'm trying to store multiple lines of data that consist of 2 values in each line

Comment: At this point, the best course of action is to make sure you understand the fundamentals.  Walk first, then try to run.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: @Sam I I am even if he uses the array that way, he's going to get IndexOutOfBounds.  Look at how he declares the arrays.  i=0 when he declares them.

Comment: I'm trying to store data read from a file into arrays so I can format it all and manipulate it into a chart.

Comment: @inspiring-wisdomhammer as suggestd either learn the fundamentals or goto a freelancer website and hire someone to do this for you or teach you one on one. this is really basic